# Catch exceptions which are not thrown locally?

Tags: java, exception

My question is related to syntactic behavior of the try catch block

Empty try block with a catch as this

```
void fun() {
    try {}
    catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

or

```
try {}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
```

compiles well but the compiler complains with

```
try {}
catch(IOException e) {}
```

Why does the compiler allow catching anything that is of type Exception or RuntimeException whereas it complains for unreachable code with checked exceptions? Is it because the JVM code can throw those types? How could the JVM possibly throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in an empty try block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The empty block is a special case which isn't specially handled by the JLS. What the JLS *does* require is that if you catch a checked exception, the code in the `try` block must have been able to throw that exception (that is, it threw it directly or called a method that was declared to possibly throw it).

In other words, there's a sanity check specifically for checked exceptions, but not for *all* exceptions with checked exceptions getting extra consideration.

This is described in [JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), and specifically:

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.
>
> ...
>
> A catch block `C` is reachable iff both of the following are true:
>
> - **Either the type of `C`'s parameter is an unchecked exception type** or `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`, or some expression or throw statement in the try block is reachable and can throw a checked exception whose type is assignable to the type of `C`'s parameter. (An expression is reachable iff the innermost statement containing it is reachable.)
>
>   See §15.6 for normal and abrupt completion of expressions.
> - There is no earlier catch block `A` in the try statement such that the type of `C`'s parameter is the same as or a subclass of the type of `A`'s parameter.

Emphasis added: it shows that if you're catching an unchecked exception type, the catch block is reachable.

I personally find the wording a bit confusing. Slightly reworded, the first bullet point just says that the catch clause must catch one of:

- An unchecked exception
- `Exception`
- `Throwable` (which is the only superclass of `Exception` other than `Object`, which you can't catch)
- a checked exception that the `try` block can throw

The second bullet guards against a `catch` block being unreachable because of a previous `catch` in that `try`. For instance:

```
try {
    whatever();
} catch (Exception e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // This block is unreachable, because a NullPointerException is an
    // Exception and will thus be handled by the previous catch block.
    handleNpe(e);
}
```