# Java compile time checked exception

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

`Exception` and `IOException` both are compile time checked exceptions.

But, we cant use `IOException` within catch block. But we can use `Exception` within catch block what is the reason for it.

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Demo{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            try{

            }catch(IOException e){ // Does not compile

            }

            try{

            }catch(Exception e){ // Compile

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this the exact code you've,, it should compile.

Comment: @RohitJain No It will provide following error because of  catch(IOException e). Error Message - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

 at Demo.main(Demo.java:6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817401/catch-exceptions-which-are-not-thrown-locally

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot catch a checked exception that is never thrown in a try block, except for `Exception` (or `Throwable`).  This behavior is specified by the [JLS, Section 11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why Exception block is compiling and IOException is not... Simply because everything inherited from Exception class, it includes all types exceptions such as IOException, RuntimeException, etc. When you specify catching Exception, nothing in the code necessarily have to throw it as a RuntimeException thrown at runtime and code compiler can't predict that one happening. But IOException is a specific exception that happens only in certain cases, thus compiler knows exactly when it might happen, and if it doesn't detect any code that might throw it, it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

See, the main reason is, you can catch any RuntimeException, doesn't matter it is thrown from the try block or not and RuntimeException is the class which extends Exception class itself. So, being a parent class, catch "Exception" is always allowed. In your case IOException checked exception, it is only allowed if you try block having a probability of throwing it.